# Report viewer not showing the data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, report-viewer2012

I'm just trying to figure out how to use Report Viewer in VB.NET.

I have looked just about everywhere for a solution to this issue and have not found one that has worked for me yet. I have a report viewer, before this the report run as a result. but now when i add new column in the database and dataset and also add column in report. the data for that column not showing in the report.

code for generate the report.
   protected void btnRunReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;

```
        SqlConnection strConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnectionString"].ConnectionString);


        string strSQL = "SELECT b.Description AS Location, ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '7.00 AM - 3.00 PM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'A' , ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '3.00 PM - 11.00 PM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'B', ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '11.00 PM - 7.00 AM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'C', ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '7.00 AM - 7.00 PM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'D', ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '7.00 PM - 7.00 AM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'E', ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '8.00 AM - 5.00 PM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'F', ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '7.00 PM - 3.00 AM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'G', ";
        strSQL += "ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.Description = '11.00 AM - 11.00 PM' THEN a.NoofEmployee END),0) AS 'H' ";
        strSQL += "FROM poTransForm a  ";
        strSQL += "INNER JOIN poLocation b ON a.LocationID = b.ID ";
        strSQL += "INNER JOIN poShiftPattern c ON a.ShiftPatternID = c.ID ";
        if (cboDept.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            strSQL += "WHERE a.DateRequired = '" + cboSelectDate.SelectedValue + "' AND a.isApproved = 1 ";
        }
        else
        {
            strSQL += "WHERE a.DateRequired = '" + cboSelectDate.SelectedValue + "' AND a.DepartmentID = '" + cboDept.SelectedValue + "' AND a.isApproved = 1 ";
        }
        strSQL += "GROUP BY  b.Description ";


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strConn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        ObjectDataSource1.TypeName = "HumanResource.DSSummaryTableAdapters.";


        List<summary> lst = new List<summary>();


        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            summary T = new summary();
            T.Location = r["Location"].ToString();
            T.A = r["A"].ToString();
            T.B = r["B"].ToString();
            T.C = r["C"].ToString();
            T.D = r["D"].ToString();
            T.E = r["E"].ToString();
            T.F = r["F"].ToString();
            T.G = r["G"].ToString();
            T.H = r["H"].ToString();
            //T.NoofEmployee = Convert.ToInt32(r["NoofEmployee"]).ToString();
            lst.Add(T);
        }


        ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("DateRange", cboSelectDate.SelectedItem.Text);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportDataSource report = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", lst);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(report);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```